# DimensionMismatch or MethodError when broadcasting a function over 2 arrays

Tags: julia, array-broadcasting

I tried to create a function that (kind of) behaves like vlookup() from excel, with the following arguments

```
function foo(val::Float64, table::AbstractArray, col::Int64)
    return table[findfirst(x->val<=x, table[:,1]), 2]
end
```

Let's say I have a *table* array that looks something like

```
arr = 4x2 Matrix{Any}:
0.26 | "string1"
0.60 | "string2"
0.73 | "string3"
1.00 | "string4"
```

When I run this function with just one Float64 as argument, it works:

```
julia> foo(rand(), arr, 2)
"string3"
```

but when applied over an array of Float64 using dot broadcasting, I get the following errors

```
julia> foo.(rand(3), arr, 2)
DimensionMismatch("arrays could not be broadcast to a common size; got a dimension with lengths 3 and 4")
```

```
julia> foo.(rand(4), arr, 2)
MethodError: no method matching foo(::Float64, ::Float64, ::Int64)
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Ref` to treat values as scalars when broadcasting:

```
julia> arr = [rand(4);; ["a", "b", "c", "d"]]
4×2 Matrix{Any}:
 0.866715   "a"
 0.0901788  "b"
 0.385088   "c"
 0.404498   "d"

julia> foo.(rand(3), Ref(arr), Ref(2))
3-element Vector{String}:
 "a"
 "a"
 "a"
```

Comment: Great, thank you! Is there any way to avoid the use of Ref( ) when calling for the function, like setting it from the function definition itself?

Comment: Well, 2 is already a scalar so you could write 2 instead of `Ref(2)`, but no if you want to treat an array or iterable as a scalar in broadcasting you need to wrap it in something like `Ref`. You can't modify `foo`'s definition to specify scalars in broadcasting because `foo.(...)` isn't calling `foo(...)`, it's calling `broadcast(foo,...)`. `foo` itself is the scalar function and has no idea about what it might be broadcasted over or how.

Comment: @BatWannaBe, somewhat surprisingly, `foo.(rand(3), Ref(arr), 2)` produces `ArgumentError: invalid index: nothing of type Nothing`. I think this is because integers are iterable: `for k in 2 ...` is a valid loop, and `[2...]` successfully "unpacks" the integer `2`... for some reason

Comment: Numbers do work as scalars, for example `f(x,y) = x+y; f.(1:3, 10)`. Good fact check about them being iterable, though, `iterate(2)` does in fact work. Maybe it's the `findfirst`? That can return a `nothing` if an entry isn't found, and if you try to index with `table[nothing, 2]`, you'd get that error.